# Uniqueness in interpolation of Hilbert spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, interpolation-spaces

I am wondering under what condition it is true that for Hilbert spaces $H$ and $H_0$ such that $H \hookrightarrow H_0$ there is uniqueness in the existence of a Hilbert space $H_1 \hookrightarrow H$ such that
$$
H = [H_0, H_1]_{\theta, 2},
$$
where $0 < \theta < 1$.

My original motivation actually concerns Sobolev spaces. For some domain $X \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $s \geq 0$ note $H^s(X)$ the Sobolev space of functions $f \in L^2(X)$ such that:
$$
\Vert f \Vert_{H^s(X)}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \vert \hat{f}(\omega) \vert^2 (1 + \vert \omega \vert^2)^s d\omega < \infty , 
$$
where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. Then I know that for $\beta > \alpha > 0$ one can show
$$
H^\alpha(X) = [L^2(X), H^\beta(X)]_{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}, 2},
$$
but is $H^\beta(X)$ the only Hilbert space (in the sense of equivalent norms) realizing the above equality ?

I am new to the theory of interpolation-spaces so I hope this question makes sense. I couldn't find results in this direction in the literature, is there a reference for this question ?

Comment: A counter example, for $X$ to be a Lipschitz domain, $\mathrm{H}^{1}_0(X)$ and $\mathrm{H}^{1}(X)$ are such that

$$[\mathrm{L}^2(X),\mathrm{H}^{1}_0(X)]_{\theta,2} = \mathrm{H}^{\theta}_0(X) = \mathrm{H}^{\theta}(X) = [\mathrm{L}^2(X),\mathrm{H}^{1}(X)]_{\theta,2}\text{ , }\quad \theta\in(0,\frac{1}{2}).$$